# Zooming CALayer blurs the view

Tags: ios, ios6, core-animation

I want to zoom a CAlayer placed on UIView, and this view is on UISCrollview. I'm using scrollviews delegate methods for zooming. It zooms but it blurs. How to remove blur and improve zooming?

I have tried with CATiledLayer but I don't want to show tiling effect. So how can I improve zooming using CALayer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar experience when zooming in content. When a UIScrollView is zooming, it takes a snapshot of the View, and zooms in on that picture. This is the reason it gets blocky when zooming. When the zooming/panning is complete, use the delegate to re-render the content according to your zoom level. The content then should be 'crisp'.

Warning: do not zoom in too far, the memory used by the snapshot will soon be larger than your available memory.

I didn't use images, but CAShapeLayers and paths. I put together a demo project and explanation here : http://simplicate.weebly.com/1/post/2013/06/fixing-blocky-paths-in-ios.html

I hope that helps.

Comment: It was over 5 years ago